# php - How to keep subdirectories when uploading?

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

Currently, I'm developing an application for uploading folders and files. I have two problems:
I can't upload files by keeping the tree (subfolders and their files).Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" action='post_upload.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

post_upload.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name) {
    if (strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], 'upload/'.$name)) {
            echo $name."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

If this problem is resolved, then it is possible to select more than one folder?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38546788/upload-files-in-folder-subdirectories-using-webkitdirectory-and-java-servlet ?

Comment: I think there is no way to skip sub-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is alternative way to do it using javascript. In javascript you will get `webkitRelativePath`. check example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Z4Amr/107/)